# On planning a road-trip

Tags: planning, road-trips

We are planning a road trip for the summer and are wondering how we can make the most of it.

How do you plan a road trip to make the most out the experience, and out of your money?

Comment: As a general rule, if there's probably a book that answers your question, it's not a good candidate for Stack Exchange. This question is way too broad.

Answer (score 3):

**TIPS**

- Know where to fill up - gas can have a huge difference from state to state / province to province
- Just because it is the most expensive does **NOT** make it the best or most fun
- If you know people that have done this track, ask them what they liked and where they stopped
- Wal-Mart's are good places to get snacks and nap
- Bring **A LOT** of music

**PLANNING**

Map out your route using rough estimates (Fill up every X kms, Sleep at B, Eat at C, etc..).  But do not expect to follow it to the dot.  I find the most fun in a road trip is randomness and unpredictability of the trip.  Ensure you over budget every.  Plan for a break down, have safety cash.  There have been numerous times on road trips where, something "fun" has happened.